# UITextView wont respond to changes in its frame

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
[message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[message setFrame:CGRectMake(message.frame.origin.x, message.frame.origin.y, message.frame.size.width, 20)];
```

The background color changes so the connection in IB is fine but the size of the UITextView doesn't change. I've tried multiple ways and can't get it to change positions or size.

It works if I put in on an action from a button but not in the callback from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut // Doesnt really matter since its so fast
                     animations:^{
                         [message setFrame:CGRectMake(message.frame.origin.x, message.frame.origin.y, message.frame.size.width, 20)];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){[message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; }];
```

Comment: Set the frame to some rediculously large value.  It could be that the frame change is too small be visible.

Comment: where are you calling this from?  If its after the view has loaded youll have to animate the frame change.

Comment: it's in a function that's called from a button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
delay:0.0
options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut // Doesnt really matter since its so fast
animations:^{
    [message setFrame:CGRectMake(message.frame.origin.x, message.frame.origin.y, message.frame.size.width, 20)];
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
```

Comment: This let me see that something else was resizing my textview. Now I just need to figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you calling this code from? Chances are that your frame setting is being over-written by a subsequent change. Frame sizes are not set yet in `viewDidLoad` but they should be set by the time `viewWillAppear` is called - so perform your additional layout there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out that, to get the content size of a UITextView (and thus set its frame to 'fit' its contents, no scroll needed) you need to add the text view as a subview **first**. Until it becomes a child view, contentSize does not return the correct value (and perhaps setting the frame doesn't work similary?).

Just a guess...